# edit main file MATLAB - msgbox and questdlg

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I have a simple question. I am using questdlg and msgbox to gather user input. When I compile my project using MATLAB compiler, the font is extremely small when I run the app.

Can I increase the font size? Do I increase the font size of the main files of my MATLAB or edit files of the runtime compiler? Or do I make my own version of questdlg and `msgbox` and then call this in?

Is it possible to centre the `msgbox` text somehow via `set(groot,'defaultUicontrolFontSize', 18)`?

Comment: you can try that https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/73331

Answer (score 0):

You do neither, you can change the foot size, this is untested as I'm not in front of Matlab just now, but you add this in your code

```
set(0,'defaulttextfontsize',12); % pre r2014b
set(groot,'defaulttextfontsize',12); % post r2014b
```

**edit**

Okay change plan for msgbox - it looks like I was wrong on that front and msgbox uses default factory settings which cant be changed.

If I was you I would make a copy of `msgbox` and rename it `mymsgbox` (or similar) - that way you control the code completely...

For questdlg you should be able to use:

```
set(groot,'defaultUicontrolFontSize', 18)
```

Note: msgbox and inputdlg are in essence GUI - just GUI which were created by Mathworks for you to easily use...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried both options, I am using r2014b. None worked unfortunately. I am not using a GUI, just asking questions via msgbox and inputdlg throughout.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. Your advice on the questdlg worked a treat! If I renamed msgbox to mymsgbox, how would I load this into my project? I am exporting my project via the Application Compiler.

Comment: You add your new file to your deploytool project file so that it gets included in your compilation.  Either add your file using the + button on the "files required to run" or recreate your whole project and Matlab will automatically identify your new `mymsgbox` file.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. Everything is working well! The last bit of help is the font size of the inputdlg. is there any simple code like you have provided for other commands to increase the font size? Cheers.

Comment: It looks like inputdlg is also using factory settings - so same solution as the msgbox.